# image swap in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have an image within a popup that I would like to be swapped out with another image when clicked. I check localStorage to know whether the "on" or "off" button should be displayed.

popup.html:

```
<body>
<div>
<img id="onOffButton" src="img/on_button.png" onclick="onOff()" />
</div>
</body>
```

popup.js:

```
function onOff() {
    var onOffButton = document.getElementById("onOffButton");

    if (localStorage.ToneSet === "off") {
        onOffButton.src="img/on_button.png";
    } else {
        onOffButton.src="img/off_button.png";
    }
}
```

Currently my `localStorage.ToneSet` is set to "on" so my image should flip from "on_button.png" to "off_button.png", but it continues to display on_button.png. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/EX2hj/1/

Comment: Not sure why my original approach failed to work, but I was able to apply your example code to a workable solution. Thanks zenril!

Answer (score 0):

I dunno this worked for me when I created a random test.html

```
<div id="onOffButton" style='width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid' onclick='toggle()'> </div>
<script>
    function toggle(){
        alert("a");
        var onOffButton = document.getElementById("onOffButton");
        if (localStorage.ToneSet == "off") {
           onOffButton.style.background = "red";
           localStorage.ToneSet = "on";
        } else {
           onOffButton.style.background = "green";
           localStorage.ToneSet = "off";
        }
    }
    toggle();
</script>
```